# How can I integrate an existing remote repo in my local folder

Tags: git

So I have a folder of code. One of the SysAdmins sent me an email saying....here's a repo use it for your code.

How can I start using that repo without having to move my stuff out of the way. i've always started my own repos or have used one from scratch "git clone"...not this ini between situation.

Just want to start using the repo...the remote one only has 1 file .gitignore in it.

Comment: Just move your files into the repository, add them and make a commit. Or do you already have your own repository?

Comment: Do you want to add another repo in your repo?

Comment: Use [`git remote add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) the [`git checkout master`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) and you should be ready to go further.

Answer (score 1):

I know this situation. You just need to add the remote target to your local  repo and then force push your master branch into the remote repo:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
git push --force origin master
```

The target url can be found on the page of the repo. On Github/Gitlab there is somewhere on the top right corner a clone button to the url.